# Using Jenkins to send Slack messages

Tags: continuous-integration, jira, slack

I'm using Jira plugin for jenkins.
https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/steps/search/jira_jql_search/
and can't run a JQL query. 
I'm trying to search for a specific project and using this example:

```
node {
  stage('JIRA') {
    withEnv(['JIRA_SITE=*****']) {
      def issues = jiraJqlSearch jql: 'PROJECT = ****'
      echo issues.data.toString()
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting

```
JIRA: Site - **** - Search JQL: PROJECT = **** startAt: 0 maxResults: 1000
Error Code: -1
Error Message: null value
[Pipeline] echo
null
[
```

I am able to use jira GetIssue and successfully get the response so I don't really understand why one call success and the other isn't.
the response I get is not helping me to understand.

Does anyone dealt with that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a null pointer in: issues.data.toString(). Can you try first to print `issues`? So maybe `issues.data delivers` null when you call `toString()` on null.
You can build some null checks and print your object out one by one.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't helped.
I've added an: "echo issues" to the code right after 
def issues = jiraJqlSearch jql: 'PROJECT = *******'
And the code is failing before it's get there.